# HA Server settings for Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, passenger

We are using Rails 3.2 and Ruby 193 over Nginx and Apache.

May I know the best options to provide a HA(High Availablity) setup.

Example:

2 servers for MySQL DB, 2 server for Nginx-Passenger with NodeBalanver. Does it make sense?

Thank you.

Prabu